# c# - Retrieving a value from Object array

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, object

I am calling an external API from my c# application which returns the data in the form a json array, the response body looks like below

```
    {
        "result": [
            {
                "name": "Tom",
                "id": "EM123"
            },
            {
                "name": "John",
                "id": "EM154"
            }
        ]
    }
```

In my c# application i want to retrive only the Id of the 1st element, for the above response body it wil be EM123..

Above is a sample code, from my Object array obj i would like to retrieve "EM123"

Comment: Desieralise the json as an array of concrete class, then use `ToDictionary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first recommendation would be to use https://app.quicktype.io.  If you feed it a JSON response as you provided it will give you the appropriate C# object definition.  In this case, the definition looks like so:

```
  public partial class ApiResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public Result[] Result { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Result
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Once you add these two classes, you'll be able to do the following:

```
var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(reponse);
Console.WriteLine("This is what I need: " + apiResponse.Result.First().Id);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The method mentioned above is with the Newtonsoft library. 


var response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(result)

Comment: you are right its my mistake, i used jsonresponse instead of JsonConvert